# Is the source code for org.w3c.dom.Node available anywhere?

Tags: java, xml

A am looking for the source code of `org.w3c.dom.Node` and especialy the `setTextContent`.

But whatever I put into Google all I get are JavaDoc or other extracts but never the full source code.

I would not have thought that packages starting with `org.` would be prohibitory. So is there any place where one can look at the actual source or was I mistaken and the code is indeed secret?

Comment: *Why* are you interested in the source code? What would you want to know?

Comment: It is a convenience method which is only available on Android API 8 onward. So I want to know what is inside. I probably won't need the "delete all existing child node" part but I like to know how to properly create and attach the Text node.

Comment: In that case grabbing the Xerces implementation and looking at its `NodeImpl` is probably the correct approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`org.w3c.dom.Node`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) is an interface! Therefore there isn't anything in the source that you can't see in the JavaDoc, it's only the method definitions.

What you *might* want to look at is the concrete `Node` implementation that you get from your DOM implementation:

```
Node myNode = getNodeFromSomewhere();
System.out.println("Node interface is implemented by " + myNode.getClass());
```

Comment: Thanks. Should have thought about that myself (:embarrassed:)

Comment: You _could_ have the source to the interface… but you wouldn't learn anything useful from it that isn't in the javadoc. +1

Comment: Well it is `org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.ElementImpl` — now I find the source for that. What a wild goose chaise.

Answer (score 6):

`org.w3c.dom.Node` is an interface. It is most commonly implemented by Apache Xerces:

http://xerces.apache.org/

For example

- `org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl` in Xerces directly
- `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl` in your JVM (Xerces ships with your Java 6 distribution. The source is in %JAVA_HOME%/src.zip)

Comment: Note that `src.zip` is only distributed with the JDK and not with the JRE. Also: the Xerces distribution in the JDK is moved to a `com.sun` sub-package in the Sun JDK (to avoid versioning conflicts).

Answer (score 3):

W3C "Java language Binding" for the DOM can be found on their site:
[DOM1](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-1/java-binding.zip), [DOM2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/java-binding.zip), [DOM3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/java-binding.zip)